# Parsing SQL statements ( get Column name used , where conditions etc ) in .NET

Tags: sql, parsing

n my application , i have a textbox where user can paste Procedure  , i need to parse this SQL and get the table names , joins , Columns ,Columns  schema etc.

is there a easy in c# rather than using string manupulation to do this activity?

Answer (score 1):

Without using a complicated SQL Parser, it not that easy to retrieve table, column from SQL query correctly. Let's take this simple SQL for example:

```
SELECT a.deptno "Department", 
   a.num_emp/b.total_count "Employees", 
   a.sal_sum/b.total_sal "Salary"
FROM
(SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) num_emp, SUM(SAL) sal_sum
 FROM scott.emp
 GROUP BY deptno) a,
(SELECT COUNT(*) total_count, SUM(sal) total_sal
 FROM scott.emp) b
```

You are not only need to get column like: scott.emp.deptno in the subquery in from clause, but also can't take num_emp as a column, it just an alias in the subquery.

Just an example to let you know that string manipulation or RegEx doesn't work for this, you should [fully parse SQL](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/get-columns-and-tables-in-sql-script-net-version/) to get desired result precisely.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/SQL_parser.aspx) is a project you can look at for information for starter.

Edit - [This](http://forums.asp.net/p/1591233/4032350.aspx) might help you. If not, look into using RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

The above project will not work for the big Procedure, procedures which contain more then 300 lines of Tsql , can you please provide any an alternative way to find it , as i need to use

```
using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql;
using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom;
```

asselmbles.

but now i am uable to get a code which uses the above assembles.

The main Result should be Table names and column names from a given store procedure( contain 300 lines of code).

Comment: Regular expressions cannot do this task, because SQL is not a regular language.

You can do this, but not with a regular expression. You need a full-blown parser.